# меню telegram bot python3 pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telebot

Как сделать многоуровневое меню телеграм бота.
Есть кнопки 'большой', 'маленький' пользователь жмет на кнопку 'маленький' ему выдает еще одно меню
там кнопки 'синий', 'черный' пользователь жмет на кнопку 'черный' ему еще выдает одно меню, с кнопками '1', '2' 
Скажите через какие функции это можно сделать.

Comment: Попробуй метод `register_next_step_handler`

Comment: в register_next_step_handler(msg, название функции)
Без атрибута msg работать никак(
А мне ненужно чтобы пользователь вводил чтолибо!От него требуется только жать на нужные кнопки!

Comment: нажатие кнопки рассматривается телеграмом как отправка текстового сообщения, содержащего текст на кнопке

Answer (score 2):

```
# Inline keyboard
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    # Окрашенные
    if call.data == 'start_painted':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Окрашенные')
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        y = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Да', callback_data='painted_peeling_y')
        no = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Нет', callback_data='painted_peeling_n')
        keyboard.add(y, no)
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                              text='Появляется ли у вас на коже головы перхоть и шелушение?', reply_markup=keyboard)
    elif call.data == 'painted_peeling_y':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Да')
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        y = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Да', callback_data='painted_peeling_y_iron_y')
        no = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Нет', callback_data='painted_peeling_y_iron_n')
        keyboard.add(y, no)
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                              text='Часто ли вы выпрямляете волосы утюжком?', reply_markup=keyboard)
    elif call.data == 'painted_peeling_n':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Нет')
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        y = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Да', callback_data='painted_peeling_n_iron_y')
        no = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Нет', callback_data='painted_peeling_n_iron_n')
        keyboard.add(y, no)
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                              text='Часто ли вы выпрямляете волосы утюжком?', reply_markup=keyboard)
```